# Is there Any InBuilt function or procedure/method to get Number of Records of table with bigint return type in ORACLE

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, count

I was working with multiple database repositories with Java.

In case of MySQL/Postgresql their inbuilt `count(*)` function returns BigInteger Data type to Java layer, for SQLServer I managed this by using `count_big(*)` function of SQLServer.

Now I got stuck with Oracle repository,
the `count(*)` function of Oracle is returning me Integer at Java layer.

Please suggest/guide me what is the efficient way to get the number of records from a table in Oracle which will return the result as a `BigInteger` type at Java Layer.

Comment: A bit nitpicking: it's not the database that returns a `BigInteger` or `Integer` it's the JDBC driver. But the real question is: do you actually have a table with more than 2 billion rows where this will be a problem? Also: which driver version for Oracle are you using (the number in the filename is *not* the driver version).

Comment: Not really this time, but this is quite possible to have more than 2 billion rows in a table, actually i am using a table for audit logs , which is saving all the audit entries to this table. It will exceed the limit of Integer soon

Comment: Maybe the driver "adjusts" the object returned based on the actual value. Did you try that it still returns an `Integer` even when the table _has_ more than 2 billion rows? How exactly do you retrieve the number? Which JDBC call do you use?

Comment: I am using Hibernate 3.0 to fetch records using SQL query, session.createSQLQuery(sql); JDBC jar ojdbc5.jar from 11.2.0.3 Release

Comment: You should first get that database obfuscation layer (Hibernate) out of the picture. Are you sure it's not Hibernate's fault but indeed the driver? And as I said: `ojdbc5.jar` does not define the version of the driver you use. That could be the driver version 11.1.0.6 or 11.1.0.7 or 11.2.0.1 or 11.2.0.2 ....

Comment: Is it truly returning an integer, or is it returning a NUMBER data type? Have you used ResultSet.getLong on a table with more than 2 billion rows and gotten the wrong value?    http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getLong(int)